# Sharepoint Anonymous Access and Custom User Permissions for a page

Tags: sharepoint, access-control, user-permissions

In sharepoint 2007 how can i give custom user permissions to a page where anonymous access is enabled for its parent site?

This page must be anonymously accessible but editable by only selected domain users. I cannot set permissions on page's parent site because in the same site, different pages must be editable by different people, though i have to set permissions on pages. But when I break the permission inheritance on the pages in order to give custom permissions to users, anonymous access is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you break the permission inheritance? On site, list or folder in the list level? Anyway if you break the permission inheritance somewhere within the list or library you should try to set the anonymous permission mask of the SPList instance (see here for a reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.anonymouspermmask.aspx).

I have been working with a scenario similar to yours with 2007 and did not have any problems...

Comment: Thanks @Bernd for your response.
I want to give permissions to users at page level.
Here is a sample scenario.

`I have two domain users: User A and User B.

I have two pages in a publishing portal:

http://www.example.com/en-EN/Pages/Page1.aspx
http://www.example.com/en-EN/Pages/Page2.aspx

Both pages must be anonymously accessible, 
Only User A can edit Page1.aspx,
Only User B can edit Page2.aspx.`

I have enabled anonymous access for en-EN site. But When I edit permissions of Page1.aspx or Page2.aspx (permission inheritance is broken here), anonymous users cannot access pages.